# Passing values to controller function from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm trying to make a view where user can choose how many hours ( game app) day want to play and from which hour it start and with which interval. But I'm struggling to execute the  controller action method from view.
What's wrong because if I click the button nothing happens

My view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#genhours').click(function () {
        var selectedId=$('#dayID').val();
        var count = $('#count').val();
        var starttime = $('#starttime').val();
        var interval = $('#interval').val();
        var dayId=

        $.ajax({
            url: "../Day/MakeHours",
            data: { 'dayId': selectedId, 'count': count,'starttime':starttime, 'interval':interval },
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
                       },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $('#lblError').text("Error encountered while saving the comments.");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

form:

```
<div id="dayID" >
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.dayID)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
    Hour per Day 
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    <input id="count" />
</div>

<div class="display-label">
    StartTime 
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    <input id="starttime" />
</div>

<div class="display-label">
    Interval 
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    <input id="interval"/>
</div>
<br />
</div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" id="genhours" value="Generate Hours"  />
    <input type="button" id ="cancel" title="cancel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index")'" />
</p>
```

my controler function:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult MakeHours(int dayId, int count, string starttime, int interval)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
     {
         Hour hour = new Hour();
         hour.day = db.Days.Find(dayId);
         if( i==0)
             hour.time = starttime;
         else
             hour.time = starttime+interval;
             hour.booked = false;
             db.Hours.Add(hour);
             db.SaveChanges();
         }
         return RedirectToAction("Hour/Index");   
     } 
}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? 1. throw an alert in and see if your click event fires 2. fire up Fiddler and see if the request gets sent?

Comment: Also you are building your url incorrect.  Switch '..\Day\MakeHours' to '@Url.Action("MakeHours")'

Comment: could you provide the routing configuration? doy you have your MakeHours method inside a DayController?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old....

There are a couple of syntax errors in the javascript - see the changes I made to get it working.  I've hardcoded the parameters but it should help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#genhours').click(function () {
            var selectedId = 1;
            var count = 2;
            var starttime = 3;
            var interval = 4;
            var dayId = 5;

            $.ajax({
                url: "../Test/MakeHours",
                data: { 'dayId': selectedId, 'count': count, 'starttime': starttime, 'interval': interval },
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    $('#lblError').text("Error encountered while saving the comments.");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```